# How to configure Maven local calling Sonar server?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, hudson, maven-plugin, building

I have a **hudson** server.

Everytime I build my project on Hudson, It triggers Sonar on other server to building too.

I checked the configuration on Hudson.

[image: Configuration of Sonar on Hudson]

I am following some instructions in [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-SampleProjects) , but seems it is not enough.

I have my setting.xml

[image]

And I have this issue:

[image]

What is wrong with my configuration or I missing something?

Thank.

Comment: Read the update docs for SonarQube cause the URL and JDBC is no longer valid...